# Spring: NullPointerException when calling FeignClient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest, spring-cloud-feign

when I want to call the method of my Spring FeignClient I get a NullPointerException:

FeignClient

```
@FeignClient(url="http://localhost:8080", name="feignClient")
public interface CallFeignClient {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/start")
    public String start();

}
```

Service Class

```
@Service
public class Call {

    @Autowired
    private CallFeignClient callFeignClient ;

    public Call() {

    }

    public void call() {
        callFeignClient.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be beneficial to post the stack trace of your exception as well.

Comment: Also show the place, where you use the `Call` class (do you maybe instantiate that class with the new parameter?)